# How do you correct dates in a data.frame based on another column by groups

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have a `data.frame` containing drug prescriptions (of the same drug) including the date of the prescription and the amount of daily doses. There is one row per drug prescription. Each patient in the data.frame has a unique idnr and each unique idnr can have several fillings of prescriptions (ie several rows). The data is arranged by first idnr then filldate.

The purpose of the desired output is to create a variable indicating discontinuation of treatment which will be defined as <(-30) doses left at time of subsequent refill. The date of discontinued treatment will then be `filldate + daily_doses + lag(doses_left_at_time_of_subsequent_refill)` calculated from the row which had <(-30) doses left at time of the subsequent refill. A patient can have multiple dates of discontinuation.

Example data:

```
idnr     daily_doses     filldate
1.       10            2000-01-01
1.       10            2000-01-12
1.       10            2000-01-15
1.       10            2000-01-20
1.       10            2002-03-21
1.       10            2002-03-30
1.       10            2002-04-20
2.       10            2004-05-01
2.       20            2004-05-11
2.       10            2004-05-24
2.       10            2004-06-01
3.       20            2000-01-01
3.       10            2010-03-04
3.       10            2010-03-04
3.       10            2010-03-04
3.       10            2010-03-08
3.       10            2012-07-08
3.       10            2012-07-18
3.       10            2012-07-30
3.       10            2012-08-15
3.       10            2012-09-25
```

As data.frame:

```
data.frame(
         idnr = c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,
                  2L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L),
  daily_doses = c(10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,
                  20L,10L,10L,20L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L),
     filldate = as.Date(c("2000-01-01","2000-01-12","2000-01-15",
                  "2000-01-20","2002-03-21","2002-03-30","2002-04-20",
                  "2004-05-01","2004-05-11","2004-05-24","2004-06-01",
                  "2000-01-01","2010-03-04","2010-03-04","2010-03-04","2010-03-08",
                  "2012-07-08","2012-07-18","2012-07-30","2012-08-15",
                  "2012-09-25"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
)
```

I want to identify those who have not refilled their prescription within 30 days with the following conditions:

If a patient has filled prescriptions earlier than needed, illustrated by amount of days covered by the daily doses, the doses should be assumed to be used up before starting the next fill. In other words, there should be a variable indicating how many doses are left at the next fill date so that this information is not lost when defining date of discontinuation. If there is no subsequent fill date the variable should indicate there is `-Inf` doses left

If a patient however has filled prescriptions later than supposed to, according to the amount of days covered by the daily dose, the variable indicating how many doses there are left on the next prescription should not be adjusted.

Desired output:

```
idnr     daily_doses     filldate    doses_left_at_time_of_subsequent_refill
1.       10            2000-01-01       -1
1.       10            2000-01-12       7
1.       10            2000-01-15       12
1.       10            2000-01-20       -769
1.       10            2002-03-21       1
1.       10            2002-03-30       10
1.       10            2002-04-20       -Inf
2.       10            2004-05-01       0
2.       20            2004-05-11       7
2.       10            2004-05-24       11
2.       10            2004-06-01       -Inf
3.       20            2000-01-01       -3715
3.       10            2010-03-04       10
3.       10            2010-03-04       20
3.       10            2010-03-04       26
3.       10            2010-03-08       -817
3.       10            2012-07-08       0
3.       10            2012-07-18       -2
3.       10            2012-07-30       -6
3.       10            2012-08-15       -31
3.       10            2012-09-25       -Inf
```

I have tried by shifting the fill date forward but i can only account for just 1 previous row in the groups of idnr. This was done using the `lag()` function but since patients has different number of prescriptions and since some patients have hundred of prescriptions it is not efficient using `lag()`. I also tried the `cumsum()` function but then I have issues with doses hoarding up from previous treatment episodes (which should already be discontinued by the -30 doses left at time of subsequent refill definition and thus not accounted for in newer treatment episodes).

Comment: Hi, it seems like an interesting question but I do not know how to read your data into my R. You have no newlines in it, so I dont know how to read this as csv... The easiest way to make your question reproducible is to give us the output of `dput(your_example_data)`! Please edit that into your question.

Comment: @uke Thank you! I believe somebody else already edited for me, does it work now?

Comment: @ccalle I'm wondering about your desired outcome. A patient gets a first refill on Jan 1 and their second on Jan 12. So wouldn't the expected value of "left over doses" be 10 on Jan 1 (the first refill, they just got 10 doses), and -1 on Jan 12 (they took their last of the 10 doses on jan 11)?

Comment: The first task is to convert the character “filldate” to real R Date-classed values.

Comment: I'm curious about the expected output as well. I can sort-of find logic in the `c(-1, 7, 12)` (though imperfectly), but the `-39` doesn't make sense to me, not to mention the 2-year gap is a bit confounding. A start of a solution might start with `cumsum(doses) - cumsum(c(diff(filldate), NA))`, though going big-negative might drive us into using `Reduce` (or `purrr::accumulate`). Not sure, the expected output doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: I don't understand how you got the -39 either when there was a gap of over a year.

Comment: @guasi "left over doses" is indicates how many left over doses there are left at the next fill. Its as you say, on Jan 12 its -1, which is why the row which has information on the fill Jan 12 has -1 in the "left over doses" variable

Comment: @r2evans Sorry, this was a typo. It is now corrected.

Comment: @ccalle You say "the row which has information on the fill Jan 12 has -1", but it doesn't, the value for that row is 7 in your desired output. That's why I'm confused. I have a three line solution, but it doesn't match your desired output. However, it does match an output in which the left over doses for Jan 12 is -1.

Comment: @guasi My mistake. What i meant to say is that the "doses left" variable indicates how many doses are left when the next refill is. The reason it is not on the row below is because if there is no subsequent refill there wont be a new row which the information can be

Answer (score 1):

Well I think this gives you what you want, but not all my results agree with yours.  It's more verbose than it needs to be but maybe it can get you most of the way.

```
df <- data.frame(
     idnr = c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,
              2L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L,3L),
     daily_doses = c(10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,
                     20L,10L,10L,20L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L,10L),
     filldate = as.Date(c("2000-01-01","2000-01-12","2000-01-15",
                  "2000-01-20","2002-03-21","2002-03-30","2002-04-20",
                  "2004-05-01","2004-05-11","2004-05-24","2004-06-01",
                  "2000-01-01","2010-03-04","2010-03-04","2010-03-04","2010-03-08",
                  "2012-07-08","2012-07-18","2012-07-30","2012-08-15",
                  "2012-09-25"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
)
library(dplyr)
df <- df |> group_by(idnr) |> mutate(lastdose = filldate + daily_doses,
                                     nextfill = lead(filldate),
                                     leftover = case_when(
                                          is.na(nextfill) ~ -Inf,
                                          nextfill == lastdose   ~  0,
                                          nextfill > lastdose ~ as.numeric(lastdose - nextfill),
                                          nextfill <= lastdose ~ as.numeric(lastdose) - as.numeric(nextfill) 
                               
                                          
                                     ),
                                     remaining = case_when(
                                              leftover %in% c(0, -Inf) ~ leftover,
                                              leftover > 0 & lag(leftover) < 0 ~ leftover,
                                             leftover > 0 & lag(leftover) >= 0 ~ leftover + lag(leftover),
                                             leftover < 0 ~ leftover
                                             
                                             
                                        )
                                  )
```

Comment: Your answer gets me 90% of the way. The persisting problem is that "leftover > 0 & lag(leftover) >= 0 ~ leftover + lag(leftover)" only gives the lag(leftover) for the previous row. This causes problems for example group idnr 3 row 4 as there should be 26 remaining doses and not 16. A solution would be to use cumsum() but then it would take account for negative values and also prior positive values from a previous treatment episode (marked by <(-30) doses left)

Comment: Change one of the negative numbers to 0 and then use cumsum().

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? I am wondering if a different solution would be too just shift forward the fill dates based on the doses left but that would mean you would need to adjust the fill dates over and over again until there are no more adjustments to be made. Maybe a loop of some sort? I could not think of a way to code for it though.

Comment: Instead of making leftover a negative number, make it 0.  Then calculate the negative number directly in remaining.